# Is it possible to (automatically) generate the SQL sentence based upon the input parameters to ContentProvider#query()?

Tags: android, sql, android-contentprovider

Is it possible to (automatically) generate the SQL sentence based upon the input parameters to ContentProvider#query()?

I have:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri,
                    String[] projection, //SELECT column3, column2, ...
                    String selection, //WHERE column2=? and column3<=?
                    String[] selectionArgs, //WHERE clause values: ?=a ?=b
                    String sortOrder) { //SORT clause, e.g. column3 DESC. May be null

    String database=uri.getPathSegments().get(0);
    String table=uri.getPathSegments().get(1);

    StringBuilder stringBuilderQuery=new StringBuilder("SELECT ");
    for(String column : projection) {
        stringBuilderQuery.append(column+",");
    }
    stringBuilderQuery.deleteCharAt(stringBuilderQuery.length()-1);
    stringBuilderQuery.append(" FROM ");
    stringBuilderQuery.append(table);
    stringBuilderQuery.append(" WHERE ");
    for(String column : selectionArgs) {
        selection=selection.replaceFirst("[?]", column);

    }
    stringBuilderQuery.append(selection);
    if(sortOrder!=null) {
        stringBuilderQuery.append(" ORDER BY ");
        stringBuilderQuery.append(sortOrder);
    }
    stringBuilderQuery.append(";");
```

But I'd rather do it automatically to avoid bugs and excessive code. Is there a ready method to do this (Don't ask why).

Comment: are you executing the query on an Sqlite database? if yes, then you may use the `query()` method it has several overloads and it takes most of your params as-is, just extract the table name. have a look at the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: I need the raw query-string however. I am try to access the sqlite database through command line to achieve superuser access,.

Comment: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder`

Comment: I will mark this as an answer if you provide it.

Comment: Is there also a way to construct an UPDATE sql string?